# unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor error in using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I am new to machine learning, I am implementing DialoGPT and trying to fine-tune it. But while fine-tuning I am facing issue while creating a dataset using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices.
I am using the below code:

```
    tokenizerDialoGPT = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-medium")
    modelDialoGPT = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/DialoGPT-medium")

    df=messages = pd.read_csv('E:/smart_reply/Test_Dataset_DialoGPT.csv', sep=',', names=["Comment", "Reply"])
    Comment_DialoGPT=list(df['Comment'])
    Reply_DialoGPT=list(df['Reply'])
    Comment_DialoGPT_train, Comment_DialoGPT_test, Reply_DialoGPT_train, Reply_DialoGPT_test = train_test_split(Comment_DialoGPT, Reply_DialoGPT, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
    train_encodings_Comment_DialoGPT = tokenizerDialoGPT(Comment_DialoGPT_train, truncation=True)
    test_encodings_Comment_DialoGPT = tokenizerDialoGPT(Comment_DialoGPT_test, truncation=True)
    train_encodings_Reply_DialoGPT = tokenizerDialoGPT(Reply_DialoGPT_train, truncation=True)
    test_encodings_Reply_DialoGPT = tokenizerDialoGPT(Reply_DialoGPT_test, truncation=True)
```

df.head output:

```
>>> df.head()
                         Comment                               Reply
0                             Hi                 Hello! Good Morning
1  Could you please modify this?  Sure! I will do that. But, why so?
2          Are you sure, or not?                            Yes. No.
3          What will be the MAU?         Hard to predict. Can't say.
4             Looking good to me                      Great. Thanks.
>>>
```

Now, for creating train and test dataset, I have tried to use the below two commands:

```
train_dataset_dialoGPT = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( (dict(train_encodings_Comment_DialoGPT), dict(train_encodings_Reply_DialoGPT)))
```

For this, I am getting an error: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor

```
train_dataset_dialoGPT = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( [dict(train_encodings_Comment_DialoGPT), dict(train_encodings_Reply_DialoGPT)])
```

For this, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value ({'input_ids': [[15784, 922, 284, 502], [2437, 460, 356, 2620, 262, 9988, 286, 674, 598, 30], [23722, 345, 3387, 13096, 428, 30], [1026, 338, 407, 2045, 922], [2215, 460, 356, 13796, 428], [2061, 481, 307, 262, 8779, 52, 30], [17250], [5756, 338, 7269, 257, 3249, 329, 428]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}) with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.
```

Could anyone please suggest how I can fix it? or if I am missing something?